# How to add limited hints when programming a quiz?

Tags: python

I am making a trivia quiz that allows users to solve 10 trivia questions and get a score. I am planning to provide the users 3 hints and print out `Sorry! You used all the hints.` when the user uses all 3 hints. How do I do that? I know I would need to use a `while` loop but when I used it, it does not limit the number of hints the user can get...
Can you please help me by looking at my code?

```
trivia = ["111", "222", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]

# POINTS
total_points = 0
q1 = {"A": 0, "B": 10, "C": 0, "D": 0, "E": 0,}
q2 = {"A": 0, "B": 0, "C": 10, "D": 0, "E": 0,}
q3 = {"A": 10, "B": 0, "C": 0, "D": 0, "E": 0,}
q4 = {"A": 0, "B": 0, "C": 0, "D": 10, "E": 0,}
q5 = {"A": 0, "B": 10, "C": 0, "D": 0, "E": 0,}
q6 = {"A": 0, "B": 0, "C": 0, "D": 0, "E": 10,}
q7 = {"A": 0, "B": 0, "C": 0, "D": 0, "E": 10,}
q8 = {"A": 0, "B": 0, "C": 0, "D": 0, "E": 10,}
q9 = {"A": 10, "B": 0, "C": 0, "D": 0, "E": 0,}
q10 = {"A": 0, "B": 0, "C": 10, "D": 0, "E": 0,}

# HINTS
hints = {1: "h1", 2: "h2", 3: "h3", 4: "h4", 5: "h5", 6: "h6", 7: "h7", 8: "h8", 9: "h9", 10: "h10",}

hint = 0
while hint >= 1:
  print("*" + x + ", there is {1} hint(s) left.*".format(hint))
  if hint == 3:
    print("Sorry! You used all the hints.")

#QUESTION 1
q1 = input(trivia[0] + "\nA: a\nB: b\nC: c\nD: d\nE: e\n\nAnswer: ").upper()
if q1 == "B":
  print("Excellent!\n")
elif q1 == "H" or "HINT":
  print("hhh\n")
  hint += 1
else:
  print("Oops! You got it wrong. The answer is 'B'.\n")

q2 = input(trivia[1] + "\nA: a\nB: b\nC: c\nD: d\nE: e\n\nAnswer: ").upper()
if q2 == "B":
  print("Excellent!\n")
elif q2 == "H" or "HINT":
  print("hhh\n")
  hint += 1
else:
  print("Oops! You got it wrong. The answer is 'B'.\n")

q3 = input(trivia[2] + "\nA: a\nB: b\nC: c\nD: d\nE: e\n\nAnswer: ").upper()
if q3 == "B":
  print("Excellent!\n")
elif q3 == "H" or "HINT":
  print("hhh\n")
  hint += 1
else:
  print("Oops! You got it wrong. The answer is 'B'.\n")

q4 = input(trivia[3] + "\nA: a\nB: b\nC: c\nD: d\nE: e\n\nAnswer: ").upper()
if q4 == "B":
  print("Excellent!\n")
elif q4 == "H" or "HINT":
  print("hhh\n")
  hint += 1
else:
  print("Oops! You got it wrong. The answer is 'B'.\n")

q5 = input(trivia[4] + "\nA: a\nB: b\nC: c\nD: d\nE: e\n\nAnswer: ").upper()
if q5 == "B":
  print("Excellent!\n")
elif q5 == "H" or "HINT":
  print("hhh\n")
  hint += 1
else:
  print("Oops! You got it wrong. The answer is 'B'.\n")
```

Comment: You basically need to use a counter and even the question need to be in a loop. Apart from that, you might wanna take a look at [Inquirer library](https://pypi.org/project/inquirer/) It is very easy to use.

Comment: @Vishnudev Can you clarify about using the counter method? I don't understand...

Comment: After each question, you need to check the `hint` counter variable with your implementation. That is, `if hint > MAX_ALLOWED_HINTS` then `print` something.

Comment: I have put an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be much simpler if you use proper data structures for holding data. Also, you could add how many ever questions you want with the below approach.

An efficient and readable way to do this would be as below

```
trivia = [
    {
        'question': '111',
        'options': [0, 10, 0, 0, 0],
        'answerIndex': 1,
        'hint': 'h1'
    },
    {
        'question': '2',
        'options': [0, 0, 10, 0, 0],
        'answerIndex': 2,
        'hint': 'h2'
    }
]

# POINTS
total_points = 0

# HINTS
hint = 0

#QUESTIONS
for t in trivia:

    options = '\n'.join(f'{chr(65 + i)}: {opt}' for i, opt in enumerate(t['options']))
    answer = input(t['question'] + '\n' + options + "\n\nAnswer: ").upper()

    if (ord(answer) - 65) == t['answerIndex']:
        print("Excellent!\n")
    elif answer == "H" or answer == "HINT":
        hint += 1
        if hint > 3:
            print("Sorry! You used all the hints.")
            continue
        print(f"* {t['hint']}, there is {3 - hint} hint(s) left. * \n")
    else:
        print(f"Oops! You got it wrong. The answer is {chr(65 + t['answerIndex'])}.\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a variable as a counting tool to count how many times the user asked for a hint. A simple example:

```
count = 0
while True:
    command = input(">>> ")
    if command == "hint":
        if count < 3:
            print("Here's your hint...")
            count += 1
        else:
            print("Sorry! You used all the hints.")
```

---

Or if you are sure that nothing else will happen down the `while` loop block *(a.k.a. the `while` goes back to the top)* after the `"Sorry! You used all the hints."`, you can improve the efficiency by using the `continue` keyword:

```
count = 0
while True:
    command = input(">>> ")
    if command == "hint":
        if count >= 3:
            print("Sorry! You used all the hints.")
            continue
        print("Here's your hint...")
        count += 1
```